# почему возникает подобная ошибка и как её решить, помогите пожалуйста

Tags: python, telebot, telethon

у меня подобный код:

```
from telethon.sync import TelegramClient
import telebot
from telethon.tl.functions.channels import GetParticipantsRequest
from telethon.tl.types import ChannelParticipantsSearch
import re
import pysqlite3
from telethon.sessions import SQLiteSession
import asyncio


api_id = 28335256
api_hash = 'c7cab7a06357e3b116358aa6d0c75b7c'
phone = '79935535061'
target_group = None
session_file = '79935535061.session'
session = SQLiteSession(session_file)
client = TelegramClient(session, api_id, api_hash)
bot = telebot.TeleBot("6107982583:AAGrjbdfSazg9W8mYEckyIS_RFtf3258xAU")
client.start()



async def get_participants(link):
    entities = await client.get_entity(link)
    participants = await client(GetParticipantsRequest(
        entities,
        ChannelParticipantsSearch(''),
        200
    ))
    return participants.users





@bot.message_handler(commands=['start', 'parse'])
def work_parse(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Введите ссылку на телеграм-чат:")


@bot.message_handler(func=lambda message: True)
def handle_all_messages(message):
    asyncio.ensure_future(work_parse(message))  # запустим работу в асинхронном режиме

async def work_parse(message):
    global target_group
    target_group = message.text

    await bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Производится парсинг...")
    participants = await get_participants(target_group)
    phone_regex = re.compile(r"\+?\{7,16}")
    for user in participants:
        if user.phone:
            phone = re.findall(phone_regex, user.phone)[0]
            print(phone)
    target_group = None

async def main():
    bot_pooling = asyncio.create_task(bot.polling(none_stop=True))
    await bot_pooling
    await asyncio.wait([work_parse(message)])

asyncio.run(main())
```

и возникает следующая ошибка:

```
   raise RuntimeError('There is no current event loop in thread %r.'
RuntimeError: There is no current event loop in thread 'WorkerThread1'.
```

пробовал уже кучу вариантов, но не помогает, подскажите пожалуйста что делать